# Jquery Chosen plugin. Select multiple of the same option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the chosen plugin to build multiple select input fields. See an example here: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select

The default behavior disables an option if it has already been selected. In the example above, if you were to select "Afghanistan", it would be greyed out in the drop-down menu, thus disallowing you from selecting it a second time.

I need to be able to select the same option more than once. Is there any setting in the plugin or manual override I can add that will allow for this?

Answer (score 3):

I created a version of chosen that allows you to select the same item multiple times, and even sends those multiple entries to the server as POST variables. Here's how you can do it (fairly easily, I think):

*(Tip: Use a search function in chosen.jquery.js to find these lines)*

---

Change:

```
this.is_multiple = this.form_field.multiple;
```

To:

```
this.is_multiple = this.form_field.multiple;
this.allows_duplicates = this.options.allow_duplicates;
```

---

Change:

```
classes.push("result-selected");
```

To:

```
if (this.allows_duplicates) {
  classes.push("active-result");
} else {
  classes.push("result-selected");
}
```

---

Change:

```
this.form_field.options[item.options_index].selected = true;
```

To:

```
if (this.allows_duplicates && this.form_field.options[item.options_index].selected == true) {
  $('<input>').attr({type:'hidden',name:this.form_field.name,value:this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value}).appendTo($(this.form_field).parent());
} else {
  this.form_field.options[item.options_index].selected = true;
}
```

---

Then, when calling `chosen()`, make sure to include the `allows_duplicates` option:

```
$("mySelect").chosen({allow_duplicates: true})
```

Comment: Thanks mate - really helpful !

Answer (score 2):

@adam's Answer is working very well but doesn't cover the situation that someone wants to delete some options.

So to have this functionality, alongside with Adam's tweaks you need to add this code too at:

```
Chosen.prototype.result_deselect = function (pos) {

  var result_data;
  result_data = this.results_data[pos];

// If config duplicates is enabled
        if (this.allows_duplicates) {

            //find fields name
            var $nameField = $(this.form_field).attr('name');
            // search for hidden input with same name and value of the one we are trying to delete
            var $duplicateVals = $('input[type="hidden"][name="' + $nameField + '"][value="' + this.form_field.options[result_data.options_index].value + '"]');

            //if we find one. we delete it and stop the rest of the function
            if ($duplicateVals.length > 0) {

                $duplicateVals[0].remove();
                return true;
            }

        }
....
```

Comment: Nice work, @IseNgaRt!

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround, use the below code on each selection (in select event) or while popup opened:

```
$(".chosen-results .result-selected").addClass("active-result").removeClass("result-selected");
```

The above code removes the **result-selected** class and added the **active-result** class on the li items. So each selected item is considered as the active result, now you can select that item again.

Comment: I tried adding that code to my select event: `$(".chzn-select").select(function() {\\code here});` That doesn't work, as the chosen jQuery overwrites the select with divs and whatnot, thus resulting in the select event not triggering. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually in chosen, when you select a value then the `result-selected` class added to intimate that the value has selected. so that we overwrite that class and replaces to the default class. Inside your select event, place a debugger and confirm that the select event is completed. otherwise try this code in **popup open**  event.

Comment: The actual concept is, when you run the code at that time the selection should be completed. (i.e) `result-selected` class should be  added in the corresponding item.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but that doesn't appear to work. This is what I have in a <script> tag at the head of my doc `$(".chzn-select").select(function() {
alert( "Handler for .select() called." ); 
});`

Comment: Still if you can't solve this then simply replace the **result-selected** word to **active-result** in the source file `chosen.jquery.js`. This word occurs 4 times in this file. It surely works but it is not a solution.

Comment: @SoundarR This partially works, so thanks for that, but if we remove the result-selected class then the only results that are passed on POST are ones with the result-selected class.